# Ajax/JSON the server responded with a status of 415 (Unsupported Media Type)

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json, live

The current project I'm working on requires me to talk with the windows live API.  I use an AJAX request to receive a JSON object with the user details.
How ever I keep getting this error:
*Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 415 (Unsupported Media Type)*

My first idea was to add a "&callback=?" the url. But then I get *"Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :"* in the JSON response.

I've been searching on how I could fix the error(s). But found no working solution for both errors. On top if that I'm quite unsure which error I should try solving (status 415 or unexpected token). Anything pointing me in the right direction would be greatly appreciated!

```
$.ajax({
        url: "https://apis.live.net/v5.0/me?access_token=" + localStorage.getItem('Live_token'),
        dataType: 'json',
        type : 'GET',
        contentType: "application/json;",
        async: false,
        success : function(data) {
            var id = data.id,
            fname = data.last_name,
            email = data.emails.preferred;//TODO preferred or account?
            alert(id + '|' + fname + '|' + email);
            localStorage.setItem('Live_verifier', id + '|' + fname + '|' + email);
        },
        error : function(data) {
            localStorage.removeItem('Live_token');
        }
    });
```

thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried setting

```
dataType: 'jsonp',
```

and the  `"&callback=?"`  in the url? You are calling a server on another domain and so you must set `jsonp` as `dataType`

Comment: Works like a charm.
I tried this before but I forgot the & in the url.

Comment: where we can add "&callback=?" in URl? Can u post sample URL by adding "&callback=?" @Nicola Peluchetti